# Why does this training loss fluctuates? (Logistic regression from scratch with binary cross entropy loss)

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I am trying to implement logistic regression from scratch using binary cross entropy loss function. The loss function implemented below is created based on the following formula.
[image]

```
def binary_crossentropy(y, yhat):
    no_of_samples = len(y)

    numerator_1 = y*np.log(yhat)
    numerator_2 = (1-y) * np.log(1-yhat)
    
    loss = -(np.sum(numerator_1 + numerator_2) / no_of_samples)
    
    return loss
```

And below is how I implement the training using gradient descent.

```
L = 0.01
epochs = 40000

no_of_samples = len(x)

# Keeping track of the loss
loss = []

for _ in range(epochs):
    yhat = sigmoid(x*weight + bias)
    
    # Finding out the loss of each iteration
    loss.append(binary_crossentropy(y, yhat))
    
    d_weight = np.sum(x *(yhat-y)) / no_of_samples
    d_bias = np.sum(yhat-y) / no_of_samples
    
    weight = weight - L*d_weight
    bias = bias - L*d_bias
```

The training above goes fine since the weight and bias are properly adjusted. But my question here is that, why the loss graph appears to be very fluctuating?
[image]

I have ever tried implementing linear regression and the loss appears to be constantly decreasing.
[image]

Is there anything incorrect in my logistic regression implementation? If my implementation is already correct, why does it fluctuate that way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to optimize hyperparameters to see if the problem solves or not. One thing that can be done is to change the type of optimizers that you used. For instance, you can use **Fmin_tnc** instead of **gradient descent**.

Besides, you can tune the epochs, L and type of solvers (‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’) if you use sklearn for regression.